# filtering CreateAPIView view with Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a CreateAPIView class based view and I need to filter the queryset defined in the serializer at run time by something that is available to me from the request. Is there any way to do that?

The serializer has this code:

```
class AssignWorkItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer, WorkitemSerializerMixin):
    assigneeIds = serializers.ListSerializer(
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            queryset=get_user_model().objects.filter(userrole__role__name='analyst')
        ),
        source='assignees'
    )
```

It is failing because that query returns multiple rows.

Comment: A CreateAPIView does not fetch or retrieve results from a queryset, what do you expect this to affect or what is your desired result?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Thanks!

Comment: As Iain mentioned the `CreateAPIView` do not call the `get_queryset(...)` by its implementation. What do you need to filter precisely? What is the current behaviour and what is the expected behaviour you want to achieve? @LarryMartell

Comment: I didn't write the original code. The current code fails because the query in the serializer returns multiple rows. I need to add an additional filter on something I can get from the request so that it returns a single row.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AssignWorkItemView(ListCreateAPIView):
 permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsManager]
 serializer_class = AssignWorkItemSerializer

 def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    name = self.request.query_params.get('name')

    if name:
        queryset = queryset.filter(name=name)
    return queryset
```

Can you try like this.

Comment: get_queryset is still not called.

Comment: get_queryset is called for a GET, but this API is a POST.

Comment: I have updated the original question to hopefully be clearer as to my use case and desired result.